# What's wrong with my XSD schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

Here is the schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="entry">
    <xs:attribute name="key" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="p">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="entry" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This XML should fail validation against this schema, because `key` attribute is missed:

```
<p><entry/></p>
```

But it doesn't fail. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` attribute in the `entry` element defintion does not link to a type definition.

You just have to add a reference to the type in your `entry` element definition (to effectively type it) :

```
<xs:element type="entry" name="entry" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```